# Python: How to turn two for-statements into one?

Tags: python, parsing, csv, export, scrapy

I'm trying to parse a web table and export certain data into a csv file.

I'm ignorant to forming two XPaths followed by a single for-statement (or maybe two is correct?).

Current Spider:

```
class MySpider(BaseSpider):
    symbols = ["SCMP"]
    name =  "dozen"
    allowed_domains = ["yahoo.com"]     
    start_urls = ["http://finance.yahoo.com/q/is?s=SCMP&annual"]

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        revenue = response.xpath('//td[@align="right"]/strong/text()')
        date = response.xpath('//tr[@class="yfnc_modtitle1"]/th/text()')
        items = []
        for rev in revenue:
            item = DozenItem()
            item["Revenue"] = rev.re('\d*,\d*')
            items.append(item)
        return items[:3]
        days = []
        for day in dates:
            item = DozenItem()
            item["Date"] = day.re('\d*')
            days.append(item)
        return items[:3]
```

I know this needs work, I'm just not sure which direction to go...?

This is the output:

[image: Export]

As is visible, I can't get the dates to fill in.

Here is the html I'm parsing the dates from:

```
<TR class="yfnc_modtitle1" style="border-top:none;">

<th scope="col" style="border-top:2px solid #000;text-align:right; font-weight:bold">Dec 31, 2014</th>

<th scope="col" style="border-top:2px solid #000;text-align:right; font-weight:bold">Dec 31, 2013</th>
<th scope="col" style="border-top:2px solid #000;text-align:right; font-weight:bold">Dec 31, 2012</th>
</TR>
<tr>
<td colspan="2">
```

Answer (score 6):

```
for rev, day in zip(revenue, dates):
    pass # code here
```

Comment: This is brilliant. I thought there must be a way to do something like this, but had no idea how to work it.

Answer (score 3):

```
class MySpider(BaseSpider):
    symbols = ["SCMP"]
    name =  "dozen"
    allowed_domains = ["yahoo.com"]     
    start_urls = ["http://finance.yahoo.com/q/is?s=SCMP&annual"]

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        revenue = response.xpath('//td[@align="right"]/strong/text()')
        date = response.xpath('//tr[@class="yfnc_modtitle1"]/th/text()')
        items = []
        for rev, day in zip(revenue, dates):
            item = DozenItem()
            item["Revenue"] = rev.re('\d*,\d*')
            item["Date"] = day.re('\d*')
            items.append(item)
        return items[:3]
```

Comment: is `zip()` named arbitrarily or is it specific to scrapy somehow? Does it maintain sequential order?

Comment: `zip` is a builtin. The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) explains it better than I can.

Comment: `The left-to-right evaluation order of the iterables is guaranteed.` Python docs. Thanks!